# Introductions to Ehresmann connections and Chern-Simons forms

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, connections

I am looking for introductory texts on Ehresmann connections and Chern-Simons forms. I seek detailed, hands-on presentation. Please, recommend sources that employ a differential forms approach rather then the algebro-topological one. Of course, the latter is also welcome.

Let me state my background. My understanding of homological group theory and algebraic topology is poor. I have basic knowledge of differential forms and differential topology. I am vaguely familiar with characteristic classes and invariant polynomials.

Comment: Sounds like you are reading Nakahara's book?

Comment: I am aware of Nakahara's book, and I will be reading it, @bechira.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about two things:

1. Ehresmann connections - the theory of connections over fibre bundles
2. Chern-Simons form - a specific characteristic class

Given this, your question is essentially a duplicate of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64305/texts-on-principal-bundles-characteristic-classes-intro-to-4-manifolds-gauge).

For 1, see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296175/gentle-introduction-to-fibre-bundles-and-gauge-connections) and links therein.

For 2, I like:

- [Morita](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821393)
- Later chapters of [Bott & Tu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387906134)

Comment: Thank you, Bechira. I am sorry but Morita treats not the construction of the Chern-Simons form. Moreover I find no mention of Chern-Simons theory in  Bott & Tu.

Comment: It depends on whether you want to learn about chern Simons forms or chern Simons theory. The former is a characteristic class, once you get acquainted with characteristic classes there should be no issue with understanding it from review papers. The latter is a topological field theory due to Written, on which there are numerous physics textbooks, but this is not the correct site to ask for that.

Comment: I beg your pardon. What are some physics textbooks treating Chern-Simons theory?

Comment: See [this MO  thread](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://mathoverflow.net/questions/359/a-reading-list-for-topological-quantum-field-theory&ved=0CDQQFjAAahUKEwionMWA7JTGAhVNNYgKHTEdADg&usg=AFQjCNHMUT5LzxWk1U6CbTvnVhlTiRfwvg&sig2=54ePjaX2s6ohML-nbYJDMA) and [this physics SE thread](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41589/reading-list-in-topological-qft&ved=0CDcQFjABahUKEwionMWA7JTGAhVNNYgKHTEdADg&usg=AFQjCNFTEmTkFWgQvQ7wCGKBJIwggVHXvw&sig2=qbCSziAxDh77YwTRT2sMLw)

Comment: Thank you again. Which review papers do you recommend for Chern-Simons forms?